# Convert a CGPointo to Int in swift

Tags: swift, cgpoint

I'm building a class to handle with a basic graphic. I'm a newby and I'm on a self learning project to build small apps in Swift for IOS devices, since I found the language very easy to learn.

I've set in my class of type `UIView` two constants of type `CGPoint`:

```
let heigh = bounds.size.heigh
let width = bounds.size.width
```

These 2 variables are `CGFloat`, but I need them to be Int.
Appreciate help to convert them to these type value.

Comment: `heigh.x` `heigh.y` no?

Comment: The referenced thread is about `Float`, but all answers would apply to `CGFloat` or `Double` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to convert the float value to an Integer like this:

```
let height = Int(bounds.size.height)
```

Comment: Your second suggestion  will cause a compiler warning and *crash* at runtime. – The first suggestion is correct, but is not a type cast.

Comment: Yes, I'm just testing it now, Will update in a moment

Comment: Yes, 2nd answer just crash! I'm using swift 2.0. First answer is the correct one! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Corrected the mistake